Как склонять названия турецких блюд?
Помогите разобраться со склонением названия «балык экмек»:

«О чём говорят мужчины, если им давно за 50 и они прилетели на выходные в Турцию? Нет, не о кошках, пахлаве или балыке экмеке».


Правильно:
О чём говорят мужчины, если им давно за 50 и они прилетели на выходные в Турцию? Нет, не о кошках, пахлаве или балык экмеке.
Пояснение
Это цельное название, и в такой записи нужно склонять только второе слово по образцу существительного м. р. 2-го склонения. Для сравнения: в русском языке могут могут склоняться оба слова, если это приложение перед определяемым существительным.
Из Сети:
Рыба в хлебе, или по-турецки балык экмек, тоже очень популярное блюдо на улицах Стамбула. Рыбу кладут в хлеб, добавляют салат, маринованные перец и морковь, по желанию лук. Самостоятельно сбрызнув все лимонным соком можно разместиться на лавочках, на набережной Босфора и пробовать это вкуснейшее блюдо. Порция балык экмека большая, поэтому рекомендуем брать одну на двоих.
